# Is it possible to create a user rating on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, mobile

I want to create a user rating section on flutter. The user rating is calculated based on how many products are purchased through woocommerce. But I don’t know how to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi! You need to create UI element like rating bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user rating section on flutter using RatingBar.builder().

```
RatingBar.builder(
   initialRating: 3,
   minRating: 1,
   direction: Axis.horizontal,
   allowHalfRating: true,
   itemCount: 5,
   itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
   itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
     Icons.star,
     color: Colors.amber,
   ),
   onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
     print(rating);
   },
);
```

You can also [check this](https://www.getwidget.dev/blog/flutter-rating-widget/) for more details.

Comment: I think I made some mistakes in explaining the question to you. I was referring to a top like this


[Screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDlwhVxWeCOI6evARKSXAZMMrp2O7g3j/view?usp=sharing)